# Precision of numpy array lost after tolist

Tags: numpy

I have a numpy array in which every number has a certain designated precision(using around(x,1).

```
[[     3.   15294.7  32977.7   4419.5    978.4    504.4    123.6]
 [     4.   14173.8  31487.2   3853.9    967.8    410.2    107.1]
 [     5.   15323.5  34754.5   3738.7   1034.7    376.1    105.5]
 [     6.   17396.7  41164.5   3787.4   1103.2    363.9    109.4]
 [     7.   19665.5  48967.6   3900.9   1161.     362.1    115.8]
 [     8.   21839.8  56922.5   4037.4   1208.2    365.9    123.5]
 [     9.   23840.6  64573.8   4178.1   1247.     373.2    131.9]
 [    10.   25659.9  71800.2   4314.8   1279.5    382.7    140.5]
 [    11.   27310.3  78577.7   4444.3   1307.1    393.7    149.1]
 [    12.   28809.1  84910.4   4565.8   1331.     405.5    157.4]]
```

I'm trying to convert every number into a string so that I can write them into a word table using python-docx. But the result of tolist() function is a total mess. The precision of the numbers are lost, resulting very long output.

```
[['3.0',
  '15294.7001953',
  '32977.6992188',
  '4419.5',
  '978.400024414',
  '504.399993896',
  '123.599998474'],
 ['4.0',
  '14173.7998047',
  '31487.1992188',
  '3853.89990234',
  '967.799987793',
  '410.200012207',
  '107.099998474'],
.......
```

Besides the tolist() function, I also tried [[str(e) for e in a] for a in m]. The result is the same. This is very annoying. How can I convert to string easily while maintaining the precision? Thanks!

Comment: Is your array single precision (`np.float32`)?

Comment: Yes, it's float32. Is that a problem?

Comment: See my answer, or the answer by @HenryGomersall

Answer (score 10):

Something goes wrong on your conversion to strings. With just numbers:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.random.random(10)*30
>>> a
array([ 27.30713434,  10.25895255,  19.65843272,  23.93161555,
        29.08479175,  25.69713898,  11.90236158,   5.41050686,
        18.16481691,  14.12808414])
>>> 
>>> b = np.round(a, decimals=1)
>>> b
array([ 27.3,  10.3,  19.7,  23.9,  29.1,  25.7,  11.9,   5.4,  18.2,  14.1])
>>> b.tolist()
[27.3, 10.3, 19.7, 23.9, 29.1, 25.7, 11.9, 5.4, 18.2, 14.1]
```

Notice that `np.round` does not work in-place:

```
>>> a
array([ 27.30713434,  10.25895255,  19.65843272,  23.93161555,
        29.08479175,  25.69713898,  11.90236158,   5.41050686,
        18.16481691,  14.12808414])
```

If all you need is to convert numbers to strings:

```
>>> " ".join(str(_) for _ in np.round(a, 1)) 
'27.3 10.3 19.7 23.9 29.1 25.7 11.9 5.4 18.2 14.1'
```

**EDIT**: Apparently,`np.round` does not play nice with `float32` (other answers give reasons for this). A simple workaround is to cast your array explicitly to either `np.float` or `np.float64` or just `float`:

```
>>> # prepare an array of float32 values
>>> a32  = (np.random.random(10) * 30).astype(np.float32)
>>> a32.dtype
dtype('float32')
>>> 
>>> # notice the use of .astype(np.float32)
>>> np.round(a32.astype(np.float64), 1)
array([  5.5,   8.2,  29.8,   8.6,  15.5,  28.3,   2. ,  24.5,  18.4,   8.3])
>>>
```

**EDIT2**: As demonstrated by Warren in his answer, string formatting actually rounds things properly (try `"%.1f" % (4.79,)`). Thus there's no need to cast between float types. I'll leave my answer mainly as a reminder that using `np.around` is not the right thing to do in these circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but I still can't get this right. I simple used np.around(x, 1). But I get a very long tail on each float number. Like:

array([ 448.3999939 ,  521.59997559,  581.70001221,  635.40002441,
        688.79998779,  746.        ,  808.        ,  872.40002441,
        935.90002441,  996.40002441], dtype=float32)

Answer (score 7):

The precision is not being "lost"; you never had the precision in the first place.
The value 15294.7 can not be represented exactly with single precision (i.e. np.float32); the best approximation
*is* 15294.70019...:

```
In [1]: x = np.array([15294.7], dtype=np.float32)

In [2]: x
Out[2]: array([ 15294.70019531], dtype=float32)
```

See http://floating-point-gui.de/

Using np.float64 gives you a better approximation, but it still can not represent 15294.7 exactly.

If you want text output that is formatted with a single decimal digit, use a function designed for formatted text output, such as `np.savetxt`:

```
In [56]: x = np.array([[15294.7, 32977.7],[14173.8, 31487.2]], dtype=np.float32) 

In [57]: x
Out[57]: 
array([[ 15294.70019531,  32977.69921875],
       [ 14173.79980469,  31487.19921875]], dtype=float32)

In [58]: np.savetxt("data.txt", x, fmt="%.1f", delimiter=",")

In [59]: !cat data.txt
15294.7,32977.7
14173.8,31487.2
```

If you really need a numpy array of nicely formatted strings, you could do something like this:

```
In [63]: def myfmt(r):
   ....:     return "%.1f" % (r,)
   ....: 

In [64]: vecfmt = np.vectorize(myfmt)

In [65]: vecfmt(x)
Out[65]: 
array([['15294.7', '32977.7'],
       ['14173.8', '31487.2']], 
      dtype='|S64')
```

If you use either of those methods, there is no need to pass the data through `around` first; rounding will occur as part of the formating process.

Comment: (+1) I was laboring under impression that string formatting truncates, not rounds. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. My matrix is merged from several 1-D arrays and each of them could have different precision requirements. That's why is can't use "%.1f" % (r,) to trunk them in the final displaying process. I'm now switched to float64, which is working fine, but I'm afraid more memory could be required than float32 since I data could be big.

Comment: can not is usually written as cannot :)

Answer (score 3):

All answers correctly talk about floating point precisions and outputs, but I would like to add that you don't need a conversion from `np.array` to a list using `tolist` in the first place. In fact, you rarely need to do that operation, as numpy arrays very often behave much the same, as I illustrate in the following example:

```
import docx
import numpy as np

# Your values from above
raw_data = np.array([[ 3., 15294.7, 32977.7, 4419.5,  978.4, 504.4, 123.6],
                     [ 4., 14173.8, 31487.2, 3853.9,  967.8, 410.2, 107.1],
                     [ 5., 15323.5, 34754.5, 3738.7, 1034.7, 376.1, 105.5],
                     [ 6., 17396.7, 41164.5, 3787.4, 1103.2, 363.9, 109.4],
                     [ 7., 19665.5, 48967.6, 3900.9, 1161.0, 362.1, 115.8],
                     [ 8., 21839.8, 56922.5, 4037.4, 1208.2, 365.9, 123.5],
                     [ 9., 23840.6, 64573.8, 4178.1, 1247.0, 373.2, 131.9],
                     [10., 25659.9, 71800.2, 4314.8, 1279.5, 382.7, 140.5],
                     [11., 27310.3, 78577.7, 4444.3, 1307.1, 393.7, 149.1],
                     [12., 28809.1, 84910.4, 4565.8, 1331.0, 405.5, 157.4]],
                    dtype=np.float32)

# This conversion is just for comparison purposes, both tables will be printed.
pyt_data = raw_data.tolist()

def create_table(document, values, heading):
    """Creates a docx table inside the document.

    This function takes a docx.Document, a two-dimensional data structure, e.g.
    numpy arrays or a list of lists, and fills the table with it.
    The table is also prefixed with a heading.
    """
    document.add_heading(heading)
    table = document.add_table(rows=0, cols=len(values[0]))
    for row in values:
        cells = table.add_row().cells
        for i, value in enumerate(row):
            # Use `str` for any types, but the format string 
            # only if you expect numerical types exclusively
            cells[i].text = str(value)  # f'{value:.1f}'

document = docx.Document()
create_table(document, raw_data, 'Raw table')
create_table(document, pyt_data, 'tolist table')
document.save('table_demo.docx')
```

If you change the commented line `cells[i].text = str(value)` to `cells[i].text = f'{value:.1f'}` (or if using Python < 3.6 `cells[i].text = '{:.1f}'.format(value)`), then both tables are working correctly, as you format the float values with your custom format. If you just use the string representation, the numpy values are already correct.

*Note that if you use `np.float64`, both versions will be correct!*

Using the string representation, the resulting docx renders like this:

[image: The two tables using str]

And using the format string / formatted string literal, the resulting docx looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Floats are very good at storing a large range with a well defined relative precision. In the case of 32-bit floats, this is about 7 significant figures. As you've noticed, the actual number you get when you do your rounding exercise is not exactly the number you were hoping for, but is close to about 7 significant figures.

One way to get what you want may be to use the [`decimal.Decimal` type](http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html#decimal-objects). You can construct a numpy array of these by setting the dtype to be of that type:

```
import decimal
a = numpy.array(original_array, dtype=decimal.Decimal)
```

Note, the resultant array is just an array of python objects, rather than a "proper" numpy array, so you'll probably need to roll your own rounding function, and maybe also some other stuff that won't work.

It might be better just to deal with built in python structures to get what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you don't have any control over the data being in a numpy float32 array to begin with, you can change the type to higher precision and then round before calling `tolist`.  In fact, you can even use [`astype`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to do the string conversion. e.g.:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([[    3.0, 15294.7, 32977.7],
                  [ 4419.5,   978.4,   504.4]])
>>> a.astype(float).round(1).astype(str).tolist()
[['3.0', '15294.7', '32977.7'], ['4419.5', '978.4', '504.4']]
```